# Getting data-position value from parent div on link click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to get the data-position value using jquery on link click. Here is my code

```
<div class="dfd-article-tile-wrapper tile-position-6">
<div id="f_54ae4352d493b83429617a69" data-position="5" class="dfd-item tile">
<a class="dfd-item-wrap cxense" target="_blank" href="#">
    <div class="imageholder">
        <img src="#" alt="Depresjon - en oversikt " style="background-image: url(image.png);">

        <div class="shader" style="">
            <h2 class="dfd-tile-header">Hello World </h2>
            <span class="source">xyz.com</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
</div>
                    </div>
```

What I have tried so far to code this jquery code but it is not working;

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
     jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
         $(".dfd-item-wrap").click(function(event) {   
             var text = $(this).parents(".dfd-item").find('data-position').value    
         alert(text);
     });
 });
 </script>
```

This is the jsfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/nt7243s6/

Need help and guidance. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you should access your [data](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) attributes is simply by `data('position');`

http://jsfiddle.net/nt7243s6/2/

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.data()` instead of `.find()` to get data attribute value. also use `.closest(.dfd-item)` or `.parent()` instead of `.parents()`:

```
var text = $(this).closest(".dfd-item").data('position');
```

**Complete Code:**

```
$(".dfd-item-wrap").click(function(event) {  
  event.preventDefault();
  var text = $(this).closest(".dfd-item").data('position');    
  alert(text);
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: I'd use `.closest('[data-position]')` so it'd guarantee to select an element with the needed data attribute (as long as there's one).

Comment: @pawel: you got it :)